# How to solve this 2nd Order PDE $u_{xx} + u_{yy} + u_{zz} + u = xyz$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I've just started learning the PDEs and I know the basic rules, but I am unable to figure out how to solve the following equation $$u_{xx} + u_{yy} + u_{zz} + u = xyz$$

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Are you looking for a specific solution, the general solution, or both? Are you familiar with the general procedures around homogeneous / inhomogeneous equations?

Comment: How about solving by guessing - $u(x,y,z) = xyz$ ? Once you have one general solution then it is enough to notice that the difference between any two solutions satisifies $u_{xx} + u_{yy} + u_{zz}$ = 0 i.e. it is harmonic. All in all, any solution should have form $u(x,y,z) = xyz + h(x,y,z)$, where $h(x,y,z)$ is harmonic.

Comment: @steven I'm looking for both general and specific solutions. I know procedures for general solutions around homogeneous and non homogeneous equations in ODEs but not PDEs. I've just been introduced to them. Are they the same?

Comment: @Salcio Would you mind listing the steps, how can i use the intuition of $u(x, y, z) = xyz$ to solve it, and what would be the subsequent steps?

Comment: You just substitute $u(x,y,z) = xyz$ to the equation and check that both sides are the same ...